# How to display a partial based on database content

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my show page I want to render a partial based on the value of the name column. In this case the @location.name = "Modera", how would I do this? Also, I will need to do this several times is there a more efficient way of displaying page specific content that isn't directly from the db?

```
<% if @location.name === 'Modera' %>
 <%= render 'locations/example' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always pass the variable to your partial:

`<%= render 'locations/example', locals: { location: @location.name } %>`

Then in `locations/example.html.erb` you will have access to `location` and go from there.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm not trying to pass a variable into the partial, I'm trying to render a partial based on the (location.name) in the show page. For example if the location.name = 'this' then I want to render the partial, but if the location.name = 'that', I don't want to render the partial.

Comment: Okay. I must have been thinking that you were trying to render the same partial but it would look different based on what your `name` attribute was.

Comment: Right, I'm trying to render specific partials based on  the show page content. How would I do that?

Comment: How many different partials are you looking at creating? And if you just used one partial, would your layout change much?

Comment: I'm building a website that has different locations, when a location is chose and you are taken to the show page for that location I need to display slightly different information for each location. They al have name, address, etc..But, they all have specific details that need to be displayed, like different amenities, and information about the surrounding area. While I know that would be a lot of partials, I can't think of any other way to do it in using rails. Or maybe I just don't know the correct way, I hope that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Having multiple partials sounds like a pain. And since it sounds like you have some common attributes it might be best to use one partial. You should probably take advantage of things like helpers or decorators for this. Also you might want to adjust your model. For example your `location` model has many `location_attributes` etc (Not sure if you have something like this already).

Comment: I apologize for the delay, thanks for the information. I will definitely look into both suggestions. However, could you explain why my conditional statement above doesn't work? Im a little stumped by this? Thanks again!

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to ask?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally hit enter. My question is updated.

Comment: Not totally sure. Try debugging it in the console to make sure the `location` is saving correctly. And you can always use pry in the view to make sure things are working properly.